# The number of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ satisfies $x^{12}-x^{10}=2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The number of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ satisfies $x^{12}-x^{10}=2$.

---

I don't know how to start it.

Comment: start plugging in numbers from $0$ to $10$

Comment: @illysial sorry it is abstract algebra

Comment: @Joe_Berg woops sorry about that

Comment: False. The number of elements in $Z_{11}$ is eleven, and the number eleven does not satisfy $x^{12}-x^{10}=2$. You mean "how many elements in $Z_{11}$ satisfy $x^{12}-x^{10}=2$?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 0 element is not a solution, so any solution must be an element of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_{11}^{\times} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{10}$. In particular, any nonelement $x$ has order dividing $10$, and so
$$x^{12} - x^{10} = x^{10}(x^2 - 1) = x^2 - 1,$$
and thus we are looking for solutions of $x^2 = 3$. Since $x^2 = (-x)^2$, we need only check elements, say, $1, \ldots, 5$; the only such element that squares to $3$ is $5$, so the solutions are
$$5, -5 \in \mathbb{Z}_{11}.$$

Answer (score 1):

We know that $x^{12}-x^{10}=  x^{10}x^{2}-x^{10} \equiv x^2-1 \pmod{11}$ by Fermat's little theorem. From here I think there are two solutions ($x=5, 6$).